# apex two authentication factor to login and open session after verify?

Tags: oracle-apex

i have two page login and verify code page to enter in application , when press login button check the password and user name by validation  process and send random code to user,
 after that  redirect to modal page (verify)

after verify  the code and successfully   , execute the below code to open session

```
   apex_authentication.login(
    p_username => ':p_user',
    p_password => :P2_PASSWORD );
```

i need another way to do that without send the password and username to other page ,
why i do that , because i need open session only when verify code successfully   .

any another idea please to do that .

Answer (score 0):

You could still align with typical login processes, but do not provide any UI access until the random code has been entered.

For instance, you could have an application item CODE_VERIFIED that is only populated after the second step verifies the code *in a page that requires authentication*.

Until that CODE_VERIFIED has a value, you could use it as a server-side condition for other navigation / components.

And if you need to protect pages from manual navigation, you could have an application process that checks this value on all page opens, and redirects if not present.